# How to restrict the list entry based on date difference in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, validation

I have a problem in SharePoint 2010 where I have two columns, `STARTDATE` AND `ENDDATE`, in a list.  If the difference between start date and end date is equal to 12 months then the record is inserted otherwise it shows an error.

I used the following formula but I am unable to insert the record in the list even though I am entering the correct values.

```
Values:
Start date 6/12/2012
End date 24/12/2013
```

Formula: `DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],"ym") = 12`

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the dates in MM/dd/yyyy format instead of dd/MM/yyyy format, and see the results.